# Git Push requires authorize

Tags: git

I'm first time using git. I clone repository used HTTPS, change one file, do `git add` and `git commit`, I have commit in `git log`. When I try to do `git push`, git requires me to authorize. I try to do it by token or password, but always git returns strange errors. How to fix it?

Comment: State the errors given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, it would be useful to include your full error messages here for us to look at.

Are you pushing to GitHub? If so, my guess is you have 2FA enabled. In which case, you cannot authenticate with user and password. There are workarounds to get it to work with HTTPS, but I would just recommend changing your remote (or re-cloning) to SSH protocol. That way, you don't need to deal with that stuff.